# Ajax UpdateProgress not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i am using ajax UpdateProgress bar in asp dot net with button click but query execute in write format but prrgress bar not run how to slove this type of problem.plz help me give me any solutions of progress bar

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
 </style>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    var postBackElement;
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {

        if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
            args.set_cancel(true);
        postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
        if (postBackElement.id == 'Button1')
            $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'block';
    }



    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        if (postBackElement.id == 'Button1')
            $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';
    }



 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
   <ContentTemplate>  
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
       </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

       <table class="style1">
           <tr>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   </td>
               <td>
                   </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"Text="Button"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   </td>
               <td>
                  </td>
               <td>
                       </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>

               </td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   &nbsp;</td>
               <td>
               </td>
               <td>
              </td>
               <td>
                 </td>
               <td>
                  </td>
               <td>
                 </td>
           </tr>
       </table>


  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="PageUpdateProgress" runat="server">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                 <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="image missing" />
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>

  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `prm.add_beginRequest(onPrmBeginRequest);` here.

The progress must be shown when the request begins:

```
onPrmBeginRequest = function (sender, args) {
    var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
    if (postBackElement.id == 'Button1') {
        $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

So move the appropriate code block from `initializeRequest` to `beginRequest`.

Now you can hide in `endrequest`.

**Note**:

The `id` may have been mangled by ASP.Net unless `clientIDMode` is specified. So make sure you are using the `id` like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress1`.

Comment: Just look at the source, the `id` must have been mangled by ASP.Net. Use that id. It must be something like `...$...$UpdateProgress1`